# \graphicspath{{\subfix{../images/}}} is not working in Overleaf 2021

Tags: overleaf

**Error and temporal solution:**

Hi, as I was preparing a document from a template, I copied the project and start modifying it. Despite it was the same .tex the template compiled (with warnings) but the new one could not compile as it showed me this kind od errors:

```
The requested image couldn't be read because it was not a recognized image format.
```

So, after some time, I realized that the Text Live Version was 2021 and, since this year is updated when you copy a project, it was different from the template. Changing so is easy in Overleaf and the problem disappeared.

**Where I think the problem comes**

Although the problem could be solved, the  `\graphicspath{{\subfix{../images/}}}` does not work for 2021. If I put the .png within a folder, there is no problem to insert it from that folder, as the command seems to be omited; but using a general folder for images and calling them from a folder does not work as it did in previous versions.

Overleaf - Text Live version 2021 - XeLatex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Hello there! Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. We're not aware of an issue like this in the TeX Live 2021 that was released today, but it's possible we broke something of course. Could you please reach me on Overleaf support email address and we can see what's going on there. If you add the URL of a project where you see the error (maybe a [minimal non-working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/11002) or a copy of your project or such) Then if it's something worth sharing with others, I will make an answer here. Thanks!